# Self Join a table via subquery - in the SELECT clause (Spark SQL)

Tags: sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have some data which is formatted in the following way.

The `ID` and `DATE` columns are the primary key for the table. The active column signals whether the use took part in the activity or didn't.

My goal is to find, per user, the last date it was active, AFTER the current row's date.

So, I thought to self join the table. The problem - I'm using SPARK SQL and I can't use a sub query in select clause, which contains `<` or `>` sign.

My thought was:

```
SELECT MAX(ACTIVE) from table t1, t2 where t1.ID =  t2.ID and t1.Date>t2.Date
```

However, it's not possible.

How can I do it otherwise?

```
    +----+----------+--------+-------------+
| ID | DATE     | ACTIVE | LAST_ACTIVE |
+----+----------+--------+-------------+
|    |          |        |             |
| 1  | 06/12/19 | 0      |             |
+----+----------+--------+-------------+
| 1  | 06/13/19 | 1      |             |
+----+----------+--------+-------------+
| 1  | 06/14/19 | 0      |             |
+----+----------+--------+-------------+
| 2  | 06/12/19 | 0      |             |
+----+----------+--------+-------------+
| 2  | 06/13/19 | 1      |             |
+----+----------+--------+-------------+
| 3  | 06/12/19 | 1      |             |
+----+----------+--------+-------------+
| 3  | 06/13/19 | 0      |             |
+----+----------+--------+-------------+
```

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do.  What results do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last date something was active after a given date . . . use a window function:

```
select t.*,
       max(case when active = 1 then date end) over (partition by id order by date)
from t;
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try that.